# Filtered and graded algebras, and the PBW theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

The short version, I am looking for a proof that, as vector spaces, a filtered algebra $A$ is isomorphic to its associated graded algebra $G(A)$. I.e. for filtration $\{0\}=F_0\subset F_1\subset \dots \subset A$, and $G_n=F_n/F_{n-1}$ then $G(A):=\bigoplus_n G_n \cong A$ as vector spaces.

The motivation is the following, I am trying to understand the connection between the following two statements: for lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$,

- Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem: the associated graded algebra $G(U(\mathfrak{g}))$ is isomorphic to $S(\mathfrak{g})$.
- for basis $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, then $\{x_1^{k_1}\dots x_n^{k_n}| k_i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ ($\otimes$'s omitted) is a basis set for $U(\mathfrak{g})$

I believe that with a choice of basis $x_i$ for $\mathfrak{g}$, there is an isomorphism of algebras $S(\mathfrak{g})\cong k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Then assuming the statement at the top is true we have as vector spaces: $U(\mathfrak{g})\cong G(U(\mathfrak{g}))$. So taking everything as vector spaces: $$U(\mathfrak{g})\cong G(U(\mathfrak{g}))\cong S(\mathfrak{g})\cong k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$$
The notation $x_1^{k_1}\dots x_n^{k_n}$ of the basis for $U(\mathfrak{g})$ coincides with that of the usual basis for $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, hinting/implying one basis maps to the other through these isomorphisms? I am very unfamiliar with this area, so I'd appreciate it if someone could confirm or deny if these intuitions are correct?

Comment: Nothing to do with the structure of algebra, and in particular nothing to do with PBW which is much less trivial. Just choose a basis of $F_0$, extend it to a basis of $F_1$, then of $F_2$, etc and conclude.

Comment: What has nothing to do with structure of algebra and PBW? I don't understand your response.

Comment: Your question is purely a question about filtered vector spaces. Not surprisingly, there's no need to consider any algebra structure to address it.

Comment: I'm aware my first question is purely about vector spaces, and I wasn't attempting to use the algebra structure, or PBW, to prove it. The question simply arose out of trying to understand the PBW theorem and filtered algebras, for which the my second question(s) are still unanswered...

Comment: No, your question is not currently purely about vector spaces since you assume you have a filtered algebra. What I mean is that the natural way to ask the question is in the setting of filtered vector spaces. (Of course the application to algebras is a good motivation.)

Comment: I feel like you are asking the wrong question. As @YCor points out, the linear isomorphism is obvious. The way this result is usually used is to show that the graded algebra is sufficiently big and, therefore, the spanning set (e.g. $\{x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n}\}$ for $U(\mathfrak{g})$) is linearly independent. There is a paper by Brundan that uses this technique to find the center of the cyclotomic Hecke algebras. A later paper by Ruff tries to do the same thing for Hecke-Clifford algebras, but fails because the associated graded is too small.

Comment: @YCor, Does it matter if the filtration is increasing or decreasing? Or it works in both cases? Moreover, does the argument go through for general filtered modules over a commutative ring $R$ or it works for vector spaces (free $R$-modules, respectively) only because we need a basis?